# Silverlight: How do you set the PreserveObjectReferences property on a DataContractSerializer?

Tags: silverlight, datacontractserializer

How do you set the PreserveObjectReferences property on a DataContractSerializer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. The PreserveObjectReferences property doesn't actually do anything and was probably left in by mistake.